# Trying to replicate Excel IF to search a character from a cell function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have a data with creative names like below image, using the creative name I have to take the asset details. In excel I use the below function for the same, please help me with replicate the same in SQL query.

Excel Function = =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MV",C201)),"Motion",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GIF",C201)),"GIF[image]",0))

Comment: Can you add the input and output, people who don't know excel would be able to help in that case

Comment: The input in Creative name is MV the output should be Motion and if the input in creative name is GIF the output should be GIF @Deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Fill the query with appropriate fieldnames

```
SELECT
 *,
 CASE
  WHEN (creative-name like '%MV%') THEN 'MV'
  WHEN (creative-name like '%GIF%') THEN 'GIF'
  ELSE 'Not Defined'
 END AS Filter
FROM my_table;
```